# nsupdate answering SERVFAIL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ddns, nsupdate

i've been trying to set up a domain that can be updated. i'm using bind9, i've used

```
ddns-confgen -a hmac-sha512 -k <keyname>
```

to generate my key, i've added the key in /etc/bind/keys.local

```
key "<keyname>" {
        algorithm hmac-sha512;
        secret "<secret>";
};
```

my named.conf file looks like this:

```
include "/etc/bind/keys.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

my named.conf.local file looks like this:

```
zone "<subdomain_name>" {
    type master;
    update-policy {
        grant <keyname> zonesub ANY;
    };
    file "<zone_file>"; # zone file path
};

zone "<reverse_zone>.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    update-policy {
        grant <keyname> zonesub ANY;
    };
    file "<reverse_zone_file>";
};
```

am i missing something obvious? because when i do:

```
sudo nsupdate -k <keyfile>
server <dns_server>
zone <subdomain_name>
update add newhost.<subdomain_name> 86400 A <newhost_ip>
send
```

i end up getting a SERVFAIL response...

```
dig <dns_server>
```

and

```
ping <dns_server>
```

work correctly, i just cannot get DDNS to work. i've tried responses in other threads like this one, all end up giving me SERVFAIL regardless of what i try. thanks in advance for any suggestions.

edit1:
this is the corresponding logs on the server-side when i attempt an nsupdate:

```
signer "<keyname>" approved
apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/etc/bind/zones/<zone_file>" pid=18799 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=112 ouid=112
client <client_ip>#62287/key <keyname>: signer "<keyname>" approved
client 172.30.2.253#62287/key <keyname>: updating zone '<zonename>/IN': adding an RR at 'host3.<zonename>' A <new_host_ip>
/etc/bind/zones/<zone_file>: create: permission denied
client <client_ip>#62287/key <keyname>: updating zone 'aci.riviera.local/IN': error: journal open failed: unexpected error
```

edit2:

turns out bind group did not have write permissions on /etc/bind ...

```
sudo chown -R bind:bind /etc/bind
```

fixed the problem

Comment: AFAIK a SERVFAIL  is the response a client gets, is there a corresponding error on the server side? You can increase the verbosity and separate out the specific update events to its own log file, which is useful  if you have a busy server : http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html and for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114139/2952385

Comment: i've updated the post with the corresponding logs @HBruijn

Comment: OK, so your logs say you have a permission problem. What are the permissions?

Comment: all files in /etc/bind and /etc/bind/zones look like this:

    -rw-r--r--   1 root bind  168 Jul 10 15:29 keys.local

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for acting like a sysadmin and posting your server logs rather trying to debug server issues from a client utility alone.

> apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/etc/bind/zones/" pid=18799 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=112 ouid=112

That seems to indicate that Apparmor is blocking your name server from creating a file in `/etc/bind/zones`.

The bind name server needs a place to persistently store (in files) dynamic updates and does that by creating `.jnl` journal files in the directory where your zone files are stored.  Apparmor is blocking that operation because, in general, it is a security violation when daemons and services change their own runtime configuration.

Possible solutions:

- move your zone files to a directory with the correct AppArmor protections.
  On my Ubuntu 16.04 `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` designates
  `/var/lib/bind/` as the conventional alternative to `/etc/bind`  for dynamically updated zone (and journal) files.
- Override the default AppArmor protections.

Create a local override and allow dynamic updates in /etc/bind/zones:

```
# /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named 

/etc/bind/zones/** rw,
```